# Excel Counting Null Date Column

Tags: date, excel-formula, count, null

I've created a dashboard that calculates from a table range that will expand every time the data is refreshed.

The dashboard has tables on a tab `dashboard`. The table range is in a `service` tab and has 27 columns of data. I am counting the number of services in the table range (every time it is refreshed) by service type (Column A). Now I need to limit that count by the Close Date column (Column P) in which closed is denoted by a date, but only wanting to count active cases. Active cases are based on not having a date, so null or blank. I am in essence counting nulls in a table range which expands daily. My formulas are not working (often counting all null rows beyond the table range), and I need to exclude the header Close Date.

I've tried variations of this and using `Countif`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('service'!A:A="chemical dependency")*('service'!P:P=0))
```

This one counts the header, but I don't have consistent results across all the options in the services.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use table references?

Comment: Let me give that a try and I'll reach back.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried these versions and all I got was a #VALUE!  =COUNTIFS(service!A:A,"Chemical Dependency", Active,"") or =COUNTIFS(service!A:A,"Chemical Dependency", (Table_query__511[Closing Date]),""). I just don't know what I'm missing.